# Should a link to earthscience.SE be added to the custom off-topic close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

One of the custom off-topic close reasons on this site currently reads as follows:

> Questions about Earth science, unless directly related to phenomena observable on other celestials, Solar system in general of which Earth is a part, or as an origin of observational astronomy where its movement, local/global phenomena might affect observations and measurements, is off-topic. For more information, see [the meta discussion](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140/how-do-we-determine-what-geoscience-questions-are-in-scope).

Now that [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) has been in public beta for a little while, I would like to suggest that the close reason be edited to include a link to earthscience.SE. Perhaps something like this (changes in bold, most of which is just copyediting besides the added last sentence):

> Questions about Earth science, unless directly related to phenomena observable on other **celestial bodies**, the Solar **System** in general of which Earth is a part, **or observational astronomy** where **the Earth's** movement **or** local/global phenomena might affect observations and measurements, **are** off-topic. For more information, see [the meta discussion](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140/how-do-we-determine-what-geoscience-questions-are-in-scope). **You may be able to get help at [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Off Topic close reasons](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/114/custom-off-topic-close-reasons)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but we already have a thread where we suggest custom off-topic close reasons and vote on them. I would suggest simply adding your suggestion there and see how it stacks up with community votes against others. There's a limited number of custom close reasons that moderators can add to the list (IIRC only three).

Comment: @TildalWave Thanks for the pointer; note that this is not an _additional_ close reason, but rather an alteration to an existing one, and that the existing one isn't even in that thread to begin with.

Comment: It would be a good time to add it then ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how I feel about that. It may encourage cross-posting over migration, but on the other hand not everything that we close with that close reason do we want to migrate--yet the OP is certainly free to attempt posting it at Earth Science to see how it is received. I'll let some others weigh in on this.